# Jira Connection Filter with c#

Tags: c#, jira

I'm trying to make a filter for Jira and I don't know how to set a range to catch all the existing issues.

At the moment I have set a range of 350, but the number of issues could be higher. I would like to have a range that covers all issues regardless of the number. Any recommendations? Here is the code:

```
var issuesInFilter = jiraConnection.Filters.GetIssuesFromFilterAsync(filter.Id, 350).Result;
```

Any help is very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea:,

```
 var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("http://JiraUrl", "User", "Pass");
        int totalDownloaded = 0, stepSize = 50, toDownload, filterId = 20000;
        List<Issue> myIssues = new List<Issue>();
        var iss = jira.Filters.GetIssuesFromFilterAsync(filterId.ToString(), stepSize);
        while (!iss.IsCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        toDownload = iss.Result.TotalItems;
        totalDownloaded += stepSize;
        myIssues.AddRange(iss.Result);

        while (totalDownloaded < toDownload)
        {
            iss = jira.Filters.GetIssuesFromFilterAsync(filterId.ToString(), stepSize, totalDownloaded );
            while (!iss.IsCompleted)
                Thread.Sleep(100);

            totalDownloaded += stepSize;
            myIssues.AddRange(iss.Result);
        }
```

I recommend you to put some logging and exception handling